# want to generate pdf from laravel request data

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-blade

i tried to generate pdf from my request data function. but it can't pass variable into my pdf generate function. i get requested data from this function.

```php
public function fetch_data()
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        if(request()->from_date != '' && request()->to_date != '')
        {
            $data = DB::table('sales')
                ->whereBetween('dlvd_date', array(request()->from_date, request()->to_date))
                ->get();
        } else {
            $data = DB::table('sales')->orderBy('dlvd_date', 'desc')->get();
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

i want to get this $data value into my pdf generated function like below.

```php
function convert_sales_data_to_html($data)
{
    $sales_data = $data;
    dd($sales_data);

    $output = '';
    return $output;
}
```

and pass to this function

```php
public function pdf($data)
{
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');        
    $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_sales_data_to_html($data))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

i tried this so many times but show me errors with missing argument. how can i fix this or have another method to generate pdf from requested data in laravel.

this is my routes

```php
Route::post('salesreport/fetch', 'Report\SalesReportController@fetch_data')->name('salesreport.fetch_data');
Route::get('salesreport/pdf', 'Report\SalesReportController@pdf');
```

Comment: You can do this with laravel package, hope this paclage can help https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf . and i dont know why you add tag mysql in this. it is not realted to mysql. so please remove mysql tag

Comment: @ Karan Sadana i tried with you mentioned package and i have a problem with passing data into pdf view. i mentioned above my question

Comment: first remove dd() from convert_sales_data_to_html

Comment: @Surender Singh Rawat i added dd() for testing purposes it's not in code

Comment: I see 2 problems: The `pdf` method expects an attribute which is not defined in the route. Where should this data come from? Second, the `convert_sales_data_to_html` always returns an empty string.

Comment: @Thomas how to define $data object in my route?

Comment: @Thomas in my convert_sales_data_to_html returns table view. i'm not mentioned it. my mistake. sorry for that

Comment: Where should that data come from? The user? The database?

Comment: i done it with using another library. thank all for support